# How many 3 digit numbers are there in which every the digits are coprime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can someone help me with this one?
Is there a better way to finding the number of 3 digit numbers where all of the two digit pairs of numbers are coprime than just splitting it up and checking for certain values of the Hundreds, Tens and the Units digits?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Brute force isn't that bad, really. Deleting the $0$, you should count those with one $1$,two $1's$, three $1's$. and then you are down to $\binom 83=56$ unordered triplets to consider.

Comment: Should say:  you may wish to handle $0$ differently.  In any case, you should explain whether, say, $100$ is a good example or a bad example for your purposes.  I assume that, say, $500$, is a bad example, right?  But what of $510$?

Comment: What do you mean by "all digit pairs"? In the number $234$ you might find the digit pairs $23$ and $34$, which are coprime, so that might be correct. But you might also state that you can combine the first and the last digit as a pair, causing the number $24$, which is not coprime with $34$ anymore.

Comment: And what about $32,42,$ and$43$? Norbert, please edit your question (especially the title!) to make this clear. With an example or two.

Answer (score 1):

The  numbers with sorted digits without digits 0,1 and no two equal is obtaines as simple table of digits in (2,9) with indizes (i,j,j), with lower bounds of index j = i+1 etc

{234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 256, 257, 
258, 259, 267, 268, 269, 278, 279, 289, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 356, 
357, 358, 359, 367, 368, 369, 378, 379, 389, 456, 457, 458, 459, 467, 
468, 469, 478, 479, 489, 567, 568, 569, 578, 579, 589, 678, 679, 689, 
789}

Selected with all three coprime

{235, 237, 257, 259, 279, 345, 347, 357, 358, 378, 457, 459, 479, 
567, 578, 579, 589, 789}

Add all permutations.

Comment: The question is not very clear, but it seems that the OP wants all six numbers formed by _two_ of the three digits to be coprime.

Comment: Has been done pairwise

Comment: But only for single-digit numbers. I think the OP wants to consider two-digit numbers: "all of the two-digit pairs of numbers..."